# Fingerprinting an operating system

Tags: fingerprint, port-scanning

I am attempting to fingerprint on our operating system. However when using nmap it reports that all ports (1000) are filtered. Being extremely new i know this is the network admin's cruel joke and was wondering how to get around this,.

For the record this is for a security class, not malicious behavior

Wes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the page on [os fingerprinting](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html). It written by the same people who write nmap.